# Getting a STR16 from sprintf

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i have a STR16 (psString) that i want to add too.

something like this:

```
sprintf(psString,"%s 500 Left",psString);
```

but VS says STR16 is incompatible with sprintf

what's a way i can modify this STR16 and end up a STR16 ?

thanks.

Comment: Btw, passing the same pointer (`psString`) as the output buffer and as an input string to `sprintf()` doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [swprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead, since it deals with 16-bit wide characters rather than 8-bit characters. Windows provides a similar version called [wsprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can also use _stprintf and the preprocessor will convert it either 8 or 16 bit-wide characters based on the TCHAR definition.

Note that this function  is considered unsafe. The wsprintf link above contains information on potential replacements, such as [StringCbPrintfEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

Comment: thanks, im new to c.  swprintf works fine now for what i need. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does wsprintf not do what you need?

Added link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx